# PHP redirecting problem

Tags: php, ajax, redirect

I have this login form which uses AJAX to query a database for checking if the user exist, if the password is correct, etc. Now, how can I redirect the user when all the checking is done? I have tried to just do like this:

```
//PHP code...
//A lot of different checks happens before this
if($_POST['password']==$db_password){ //Last check!
   header("Location: member-page.php");
}
```

But that doesn't work (it doesn't return any errors either):( 
So, how can I do this?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: *sigh* always always ALWAYS use hashes! This isn't secure, I hope you don't mind being the next Sony.

Comment: "Doesn't work" doesn't help us.  You need to tell us if you get any errors or what does happen when you try this.  Also, note that you must output headers before any content is written to the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing it via AJAX you'll have to do it on the page that is making the AJAX request, so you'll need to do it client-side... in jQuery it might look a bit like this...

```
$.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" },
 function(data) {
   if (jQuery.trim(data) == 'success') {
    window.location = '/member-page.php';
  }
 });
```

Comment: I have never worked with jQuery, only MooTools. So you'll need to make the login-process.php (the file that does all the MySQL work) return something, and then use JavaScript to check if it (login-process.php) returns it? Hard to explain :)

Comment: Yeah so you'd do something along the lines of if(success) { return 'success' } else { return 'failed' } then output that to the page that has been requested by AJAX. You then need to check in the JavaScript if success or failed was returned then do window.location = 'member-page.php'... I'm not too sure on mootools but they will have a method to retrieve the returned data from the AJAX request. Basically if you're doing header('Location: on the AJAX requested page it will forward THAT page, not the page the request came from.